# Submitting a form using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I've a JSP page which includes a checkbox, so when i try to submit the form using the conventional javascript way of `document.forms[0].submit();` the form gets refreshed and the checkbox values are not getting retained.

Can anybody help me on how to send the form value using only AJAX. I don't need the way to send using JQuery.

This is the code I had used for sending using form submit:

```
   function relatedAER(){
      ......
      document.forms[0].literatureSelected.value = litNO + "&";
      document.forms[0].opCode.value = "relatedAER";
      document.forms[0].target='_self';
      document.forms[0].action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/litaer.do?selected="+selected;
      document.forms[0].submit();
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Have you selected which API you are using to use for it (XHR, JSON-P script generation, etc)? Have you not managed to find a tutorial for that API? Is it getting the data out of the form that is causing you issues? Or putting that data in a format suitable for sending in an HTTP request? Or something else? As it stands, your question is not [reasonably scoped](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: Can you please provide code ?

Comment: Calling submit() on the form will trigger a REST request, what you want to do is not to call submit() but rather only a javascript function with callback.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: This is what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Quentin - i'm facing trouble in putting that data in a format suitable for sending in an HTTP request
because when i used form.submit i was able to get all the form values in action class, but in view the JSP got refreshed and the selected checkbox values were removed.

Comment: @nithin — So update the question with the code you have so far, and explain *that* problem.

Comment: quentin i've added the code i had used.. sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

I hope next time, you'll put some effort, into creating even a simple code, and showing us instead of asking for a script.

*Now, that bieng said:* This will submit a username to a php file, called `fetch.php`

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' name='user' id='user' /><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit'  onclick='check()' />
<div id='output'></div>
```

**Ajax:**

```
    function check(){
    var xmlhttp;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xmlhttp = ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    } 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
            }
        }

    get_user = document.getElementById('user').value;
    param = "name="+get_user;
    xmlhttp.open('POST','fetch.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(param);
    }   
    </script>
```

Comment: your trying to send a single element.. but is it possible to send the entire form using the same way ?
like
param = document.forms[0];
and then send the xmlhttp request ?